# Use jQuery to track all exteral links OTHER THAN Facebook,Twitter,GooglePlus

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, google-analytics

I am trying to set up some code to track all external links other than the main social media sites (they are tracked on there own already)

here is my code

```
    jQuery('a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="' + window.location.host + '"]:not[href*="plus.google.com"]:not[href*="twitter.com"]:not[href*="facebook.com"])').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(['_trackEvent', 'External Link', 'Click', jQuery(this).attr('href')]);

        try{
             //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External Link', 'Click', jQuery(this).attr('href')]);
         }catch(err){};
         return false;
    })
```

I am tying to use multiple :not selectors to prevent it from matching Facebook.com, twitter.com etc.

But my links to facebook are still triggering this. Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think it'd be more readable if you called `.not()` for your selectors, instead of putting them all in one huge one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't insert the brackets between each of your `:not()` selectors properly.

It should look like this:

```
jQuery('a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="' + window.location.host + '"]):not([href*="plus.google.com"]):not([href*="twitter.com"]):not([href*="facebook.com"])')
```

Or, per voithos' comment, put your attribute selectors in a `.not()` call instead, which makes it look much cleaner IMO:

```
jQuery('a[href^="http://"]').not('[href*="' + window.location.host + '"], [href*="plus.google.com"], [href*="twitter.com"], [href*="facebook.com"]')
```

Comment: oops, I thought `not()` doesn't accept callback, and `filter()` does. My fault

Comment: Great Thanks BoltClock... I think I was getting a little tiered when I was doing that, as I did not intend to have the () in there at all as I was using the CSS selector :not and NOT the .not() function.. but yes that is the better and cleaner choice. Cheers.